# change to two decimal points

Tags: java, android

Please help me to view the results of this bmi calculations to two decimal points.

here is my code...

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    double weight;
    double height;
    double bmi;
    String msg = "";


    if (field_height.getText().toString().equals("") || field_weight.getText().toString().equals("")){

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Valid Values!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

    }else {

        weight = Double.parseDouble(field_weight.getText().toString());
        height = Double.parseDouble(field_height.getText().toString());

        bmi = height * height;
        bmi = (weight / bmi);
    }
}
```

Comment: This will help `String result = String.format("%.2f", bmi);`

Answer (score 1):

**Try using `String.format()`:**

```
String bmiString = String.format( "%.2f", bmi);
```

**Or use class `DecimalFormat`:**

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("####0.00");
String bmiString = df.format(bmi);
```

Hope this will help~

Answer (score -1):

[corrected]

Please find the answer below,

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00##");
String result = df.format(bmi);
```

Hope, this will help.

Thanks

Comment: Test code before submitting answers. 1. `DecimalFormat.format` expects a number, you are giving it a string, it's not going to work. 2. `0.00##` will display 4 decimals, OP wants 2.